# How to make the browser read an html tag as a tag and not text

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where you can insert some text that is stored into a db. The record is then retrieved and included in a html page.

The user wants to include a href link in the text and to be able to use the link in the html page.
What I have as per now is:

- you input the text into the db through a textarea including Stackoverflow.com
- in the db the link is stored correctly (I use bindValue on the field)
- if you open the html page you see the link as a text: instead of Stackoverflow.com clickable you still see Stackoverflow.com

I know that for many of you this can be an easy question but for me it's the first time I deal with this kind of requests and I need an idea on the best way to achieve the result.

This is a printscreen of my page: exactly the same text that is stored in the db:
[image: Printscreen]

Thanks a lot

Comment: when you output the link, are you enclosing it between '<a>' tags ?

Comment: `<a href="http://www.google.com">Text here </a>` Are you doing the same

Comment: @Gar yes. I have edited the question to include a printscreen of what I see

Comment: you are most likely using the html_entities function to print out the result from the database, which  leads to such behavious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following function when you are printing the output on your web page

```
  htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
```

where $text is the variable which contains the description text.

Read more about it [here](http://pk1.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did for the links,

```
<?php 
 $text = "http://stackoverflow.com";
 echo preg_replace('@((http?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
?>
```

Comment: I see. I do something similar when I upload the link. I have edited the question to include the screenshot of my page. I'd like to see just Truckemotion 1 and to be able to use the href to go to www.truckemotion.it

Answer (score 0):

This is a protection feature from php for YOU! And you should handle it manualy and only for the a tag.

When your user can put any text (including html, css, js) he/she can do a lot of harm to your page.

The simplest and best way to solve this is to not put the a tag in y our text but something like bb code (google) and then replace it as soon as you get it from the database with the real tag.

Comment: I already filter the tag with htmlspecialchars, bind the value in PDO query and so on. I am not concerned about security. Btw the only user that can post there is the owner of the site itself. I don't want to use bbcode for many reasons. My question is not on the input side: it's on the output!